# Finding the location and size of a label in a UIImageView when taking a screenshot programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, uilabel

I am creating an app that allows users to place text over their images, and save them to the camera roll. The way I have implemented this is after the user selects or takes a photo, they are then presented with a text field. This text field then changes the text of a label. I have placed gesture recognizers on the label so that the user can pan the label, pinch to zoom, and rotate the label.

With stackoverflow's help I have been able to succesfully take a screenshot of the label on top of the image. However, when saving to camera roll it doesn't recognize the labels size or location on top of the image. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is where I am saving the image to the camera roll

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
     if (buttonIndex == 0)
{

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(_image.size);


    [_image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, _image.size.width, _image.size.height)];

    [_textLabel drawTextInRect:CGRectMake((_image.size.width - _textLabel.frame.size.width)/2, (_image.size.height - _textLabel.frame.size.height)/2, _textLabel.frame.size.width, _textLabel.frame.size.height)];

    UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"WRDIT"
                                                      message:@"Your image has been saved to the Camera Roll"
                                                     delegate:self
                                            cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                            otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

    [message show];

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(resultingImage, nil, nil, nil);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out. I placed the UIImage and the UILabel in a UIView.

Then I did this:

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(_containerView.bounds.size, _containerView.opaque, 0.0);

    [_containerView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

This allows me to handle panning, rotation, and scaling. I can then save this image to the camera roll or send it to FB, Twitter, Etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but you might try using `drawInRect:withFont:lineBreakMode:alignment:` instead of `drawTextInRect`.  Apple docs say not to call `drawTextInRect` directly.

> drawTextInRect:
>
> Draws the receiver’s text (or its shadow) in the specified rectangle.
>
> ```
> - (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect
> ```
>
> Parameters
>
> rect
>
> The rectangle in which to draw the text.
>
> Discussion
>
> **You should not call this method directly.** This method should only be
>   overridden by subclasses that want to modify the default drawing
>   behavior for the label’s text.

Here's the method docs say to use:

> `drawInRect:withFont:lineBreakMode:alignment:`
>
> Draws the string in the current graphics context using the specified
>   bounding rectangle, font and attributes.
>
> ```
> - (CGSize)drawInRect:(CGRect)rect withFont:(UIFont *)font 
>                              lineBreakMode:(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode
>                                  alignment:(UITextAlignment)alignment
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. However I am a little confused as how exactly to implement this in my actionsheet method?

Comment: I think you simply replace drawTextInRect with drawInRect.  You'd need to provide the extra parameters of course.  Again, i don't know if this is the exact problem, but docs say not to call drawTextInRect directly.

Comment: Thanks. I will look more into it and let you know when I figure it out.